# Multiplicative Order Modulo Evaluated Cyclotomic Polynomials

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory, reference-request

If $\Phi_n(x)$ is the $n$th cyclotomic polynomial, then for which positive integers $n$ and $a>1$ is it true that $\operatorname{ord}_{\Phi_n(a)}(a) = n;$ that is, when is $n$ the smallest positive integer such that $\Phi_n(a)\,|\,a^n - 1$?

My conjecture (based on empirical data for smallish values of $n$ and $a$) is that this equation holds for every $n$ and $a$ except $(n,a) = (6,2)$, in which case $\operatorname{ord}_{\Phi_6(2)}(2) = 2 \ne 6.$

However, proving this for general $n$ and $a$ has given me some trouble.

I can show that the equation holds when $n=p^k$ is a prime power:

For all $1 \le r\le p^{k-1}$,
$$1 < a^r < 1 + a^{p^{k-1}} + a^{2p^{k-1}} + \ldots + a^{(p-1)p^{k-1}} = \Phi_{p^k}(a).$$
Since $\Phi_{p^k}(x)$ divides $x^{p^k}-1$, the order of $a$ modulo $\Phi_{p^k}(a)$ must divide $p^k$. The inequality above shows that the order of $a$ must be greater than $p^{k-1};$ hence the order of $a$ is equal to $p^k$.

Beyond that, I haven't had much luck in producing a proof of the conjecture. Does anyone have any suggestions? Any references to related material would also be appreciated.